# R: Automatically 'translate' shortened URLs from Twitter data

Tags: r, url, twitter

I am looking for a way to automatically 'translate' the shortened URLs from Twitter to the original URL.

I scraped a couple of twitter timelines using following code:

```
tweets <- userTimeline("exampleuser", n = 3200, includeRts=TRUE)
tweets_df <- tbl_df(map_df(tweets, as.data.frame))
```

Then I separated the shortened URLs from the rest of the tweet text, so that I have a separate column in my dataframe, which contains only the shortened URL.

Now I am looking for a way to automatically scrape all these URLs, which redirect to various websites, and get a new column with the original (i.e. unshortened) URL.

Anyone an idea how I can do this in R?

Thanks,
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `httr` package.

`httr::HEAD("URL")` will give you a response in the first line and then you can do the usual cleaning to get just the URL-s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But I have a dataset with 10.000+ URLs and if I try something like

`httr::HEAD(tweets$links)`

i get an error message: "Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE"

Comment: Can you paste some sample of the data?

Comment: Unfortunately, stackoverflow does not allow to post URL shorteners